# Get innerHTML of class elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the function getElementsByClassName to get an array of elements and then use .innerHTML but it returns me the following text:

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control input-block" value="Algorithms to live by" type="text">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function save_book(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    var book = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    console.log(book[0].innerHTML)
}
```

and I only want the value. When I display the array of elements I find the .innerHTML returns the value but I get this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code where you're using `getElementsByClassName`? You can get the value directly.

Comment: Just updated the text

Comment: How does you function get called ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What you're showing here seems weird, you have a method that takes an event, then uses the event's target's *id* to fetch all elements with *class* equal to that id. Then you try to get `.innerHTML` from it, which is just all the contents of the element, say the element is a div, it's everything between `<div>` and `</div>`. It all looks like you're trying to accomplish something completely different and you [X/Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)-ed yourself into this 'solution'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given function, you need to grab the captured elements *child element* (the `input`), not its `innerHTML`, and with that you then get is value using e.g. `book[0].firstChild.value`

```
function save_book(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    var book = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    console.log(book[0].firstChild.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dot notation to extract the `value` attribute:

```
function save_book(event){
  var id = event.target.id;
  var book = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[0];
  var bookValue = book.value;
  console.log(bookValue)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this -

```
var dom = document.getElementsByClassName("input-block")[0].value;

console.log(dom); //Algorithms to live by
```

Comment: It returns me undefined

Comment: verify the link